Entity Framework 6 - Updating model using Update Wizard and Microsoft Entra (AAD) MFA Interactive
Our team has a database first EF6 project where we need to update the EDMX model from the database schema. Until now we have been using SQL Authentication and have no issues, however we have now moved away from SQL Auth and need to use Microsoft Entra MFA. Since EF6 does not support Active Directory Interactive, updating the model is not working.
Using other modes of Active Directory like integrated are not supported by company policy. Upgrading to EF Core is a very huge effort considering the size of our project.
The connect itself succeeds, and list of databases in the server can be viewed on the Update Wizard UI but the step where it shows the list of tables with  'Add, Refresh or Delete' tabs shows an error.
Considering this scenario - Is there any way to update the model? I can connect to the database using SSMS and Microsoft Entra MFA with no issues.
The code that uses EF6 itself works because I can fetch an access token and assign it to the SQL connection being used by EF6. The only problem is the Update Wizard. I need a way to provide a token authenticated connection to the EF6 EDMX update wizard.
Thanks

Consider it an omen of total collapse waiting to happen. You really need to make a plan for modernization lest you end up having to do everything last-minute. For the time being, just copy the database to a local SQL Server instance and do the update.
